# Users automatically being logged out ( PHP Session Problem)

Tags: php, jquery, session

I made a website with login features, but sometimes users are automatically logged out. I have other websites and have never experienced this issue before. My website is hosted. My session script is

```
if(#username and password is match#) 
    $_SESSION['front_end_user'] = $username;
```

The difference between this website and my other website is that in this website I use full jquery interaction. Could this effect the session? If not what is the problem?

I have checked all my pages and there are no `session_destroy` or `unset` statements.

Comment: Are you using some kind of framework? I got this problem some time ago with CakePHP. It drops the session if one of your files are not available (404).

Answer (score 2):

The session usually expires after 24 minutes. By the way you can set this session timeout to last more, but I'd not suggest this. I'd use a cookie solution. (For this google "remember me tutorial" and you'll find out).

Comment: thank you sir, i will try "remember me" for login with session :)

Answer (score 1):

I think this is session time out. Your session is timing out after a certain amount of time and this is a normal behaviour of all applications.

PHP's default session time out value is 24 minutes. This mean that session will be timed out after the inactivity of 24 minutes.

Although you can increase session time out limit but note that should not be big amount.

Comment: is the session will timed out althought i access the page continuously ? thanks for the answer :)